# How can I update the self-signed SSL/TLS certificate of the Docker private registry without needing to remove the existing images?

Tags: linux, docker, ssl, docker-registry, podman

I have a docker private registry deployed locally at `127.0.0.1:443`, which is protected with a self-signed SSL/TLS certificate. This registry contains images that are used during container deployment.

However, I am currently facing an issue where the SSL/TLS certificate has expired, and I am no longer able to log in using the command:

`docker login -u 'username:test' https://127.0.0.1:443`

executing the above command results in the following error:

> Error response from daemon: Get "https://127.0.0.1:443/v2/": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2024-01-01T14:04:11+04:30 is after 2023-11-12T05:19:15Z

What I did was to generate a new set of certificates and then restart/reinitialize the Docker container as follows:

```
docker run -d \                                                                                                         
--restart=always \
--name registry \
-v `pwd`/auth:/auth \
-v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
-v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
-e REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd \
-e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM="Registry Realm" \
-e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/certificate.crt \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/private.key \
-p 443:443 registry:2
```

This approach was successful, but as you can observe, it represents a fresh deployment. Consequently, all the images have been removed from the registry.

**2nd Guess**: I also uploaded the new certificates to the docker container as follows:

```
docker cp certs <registry_container_id>:/certs
```

and restarted the container:

```
docker restart <registry_container_id>
```

The aforementioned action led to the private key not being parsed, consequently causing the container to fail during the restart.

On another note, is there a method to update the SSL/TLS certificate of the Docker registry without causing any disruptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `registry` image stores uploaded images at `/var/lib/registry`, so to persist them from container instance to container instance, you need to map a volume or a host directory to that path.

For instance, if you want to store the images in a volume called `my-images`, you'd add

```
-v my-images:/var/lib/registry
```

to your `docker run` command.

Comment: Why am I so dumb!  Thanks @Hans.

Comment: Honestly, I thought it was pretty poorly documented. It's not mentioned at all on the registry image page on Docker Hub.